# SharePoint 2013 text styles "not available"

Tags: 2013

This is about SharePoint 2013. I have custom page layouts and a custom master on my page and my problem is that the content editor web part shows all of the text styles as question marks and tags them as "not available"... I have the styles in my main.css file as follows but they won't come up as intended - what to check or to do here? Am I perhaps missing something in the master page?

Thanks for any help!

main.css (partly):

```
h1, 
.ms-WPBody H1, 
.ms-WPBody H1.ms-rteStyle-H1, 
.ms-rteStyle-H1 {
    -ms-name: "1";
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #004A7F;
    font-family: 'Istok Web', Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

h2, 
.ms-WPBody H2, 
.ms-WPBody H2.ms-rteStyle-H2, 
.ms-rteStyle-H2 {
    -ms-name: "2";
    font-size: 19px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #004A7F;
    font-family: 'Istok Web', Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

h3, 
.ms-WPBody H3, 
.ms-WPBody H3.ms-rteStyle-H3, 
.ms-rteStyle-H3 {
    -ms-name: "3";
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #004A7F;
    font-family: 'Istok Web', Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

p, 
.ms-WPBody P, 
.ms-WPBody P.ms-rteStyle-P, 
.ms-rteStyle-P {
    -ms-name: "Normal";
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Istok Web', Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: #656565;
}
```

Edit:
mycustom.master (header):

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
        <sharepoint:sppinnedsitetile ID="Sppinnedsitetile1" runat="server" tileurl="/_layouts/15/images/SharePointMetroAppTile.png" tilecolor="#0072C6"/>
        <sharepoint:robotsmetatag ID="Robotsmetatag1" runat="server"/>
        <sharepoint:pagetitle ID="Pagetitle1" runat="server">
            <asp:contentplaceholder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
                <sharepoint:projectproperty ID="Projectproperty1" property="Title" runat="server"/>
            </asp:contentplaceholder>
        </sharepoint:pagetitle>
        <sharepoint:spshortcuticon ID="Spshortcuticon1" runat="server" iconurl="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=23"/>

        <!-- Custom javascript libs. Load from CDN and fallback to local. Protocal relative urls. -->       
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/_layouts/15/custom/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">$.noConflict();</script>

        <sharepoint:startscript ID="Startscript1" runat="server"/>
        <sharepoint:csslink ID="Csslink1" runat="server" version="15"/>
        <sharepoint:cachemanifestlink ID="Cachemanifestlink1" runat="server"/>
        <sharepoint:scriptlink ID="Scriptlink1" language="javascript" name="core.js" ondemand="true" runat="server" localizable="false"/>
        <sharepoint:scriptlink ID="Scriptlink2" language="javascript" name="menu.js" ondemand="true" runat="server" localizable="false"/>
        <sharepoint:scriptlink ID="Scriptlink3" language="javascript" name="callout.js" ondemand="true" runat="server" localizable="false"/>
        <sharepoint:scriptlink ID="Scriptlink4" language="javascript" name="sharing.js" ondemand="true" runat="server" localizable="false"/>
        <sharepoint:scriptlink ID="Scriptlink5" language="javascript" name="suitelinks.js" ondemand="true" runat="server" localizable="false"/>
        <sharepoint:customjsurl ID="Customjsurl1" runat="server"/>
        <sharepoint:soapdiscoverylink ID="Soapdiscoverylink1" runat="server"/>
        <sharepoint:ajaxdelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" container="false" runat="server">
            <asp:contentplaceholder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server"/>
            <sharepoint:delegatecontrol ID="Delegatecontrol1" runat="server" controlid="AdditionalPageHead" allowmultiplecontrols="true"/>
            <asp:contentplaceholder id="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server"/>
        </sharepoint:ajaxdelta>
        <sharepoint:cssregistration ID="Cssregistration1" name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server"/>

        <!-- Load custom head stuff after sharepoint stuff -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_layouts/15/custom/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/custom/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/custom/print.css" media="print" />

        <!-- Load prefix free after stylesheets -->
        <script src="/_layouts/15/custom/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Edit 2: Picture of the problem
[image: Text styles not available]

Comment: Are you referencing your custom css like this?
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server" />
        <SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration2" Name="/Style Library/css/your_main.css" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />

Comment: No I'm not. This is the actual main css which includes all of the styles needed on the page - tried to change it to that which indeed reseted the design pretty much to default. Any other questions?

Comment: And what if you don't use the After attribute? Can you upload a screen capture of the "question marks" and "not available" tags?

Comment: Uploaded the screenshot. Removing the after attribute didn't change anything, the site's styling is still broken (read: it's default) and so are the text styles (not available that is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the Lea Verous prefixfree.min.js. It's messing things up with the SharePoint parser that looks for the .ms-rteStyle- classes from the css files.

Comment: This was correct! I was using Prefixr (http://prefixr.com/) and removing this .js fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the copy/paste breaking up. To avoid these kind of scenarios, paste in notepad and then conform before bringing in.